# Understanding and Implementing Advanced Event Handling in Vue.js: Dealing with Event Modifiers and Event Filtering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I implement dynamic event handling in Vue.js when using a dynamic list of elements?

I have a list of items, each represented by a component, and I want to attach a unique event listener to each item in the list. The event listener should perform a specific action based on the item's unique data.

The issue I am facing is that I am not able to bind the event listener to the specific item using v-on directive, as the list is generated dynamically and the number of items can change. I have tried using v-for with v-on, but it attaches the same event listener to all the items in the list.

I have also researched using $listeners and $attrs, but I am not sure if that is the best solution for my use case.

Here is an example of my current code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <item-component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" v-on="uniqueEventListeners(item)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: "item 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "item 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "item 3" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    uniqueEventListeners(item) {
      return {
        click: () => {
          console.log(`Clicked on item with id: ${item.id}`);
        }
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

What is the best way to achieve dynamic event handling with a dynamic list of items in Vue.js? And also how can I make sure that the event is unique for each item.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is.  with your current code, you will print `item.id` to console for each item rendered, regardless of the number of items.  what else are you trying to accomplish?  if you have a specific function/code you need to run based on a specific item, your event handler method would simply need to check `if(item.id === x)` to run code unique to a certain item.id

Comment: What you have [seems to work](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/JWVxaFITaK2t5BWQogbf4CRGuJt6zaxg+2koCj/zjovoRTIIfasxzu7423YY1mGdYUsZonNjCzdjiv8LLVxIPCQVrmDhisAkbp0cd/vAQy6yqgRAUiHhY3hdcQADUgRw2oJKi0wBs48BVacQbucs9Yz1vpX1mbG2njWSHrrN+2DX/u7BbqTFlTVUGWl5EeFzzUq9yKtQ4XGLnymqavbvgCyXGaXGKj17e5nnE60sjrHMNfHxf7J01CAVp0XcJXu1FV913gcStHu77vi+m8qvK94CNDP4ySanoIAXS/z1CEhgETIGurgoM12sEH2ipbciC/4NYRJkAJ1oBUF/u6cs11D7voL3lto2yQiBZJKokmXLZks/EQERVqGZ6sVTUtnBWl1ByQ+2cwZjZPHnJ2cK20cRfaQ+Rk721CbY0S70FTKyQJDtEXwbvTVoqHEnA2P3uWIKFijCQwqgQbNfzln1Ju8o7ms/QZZifCV). What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <item-component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :data-id="item.id" v-on="item.events" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default 
{
  data() 
  {
    return {
      items: [
        { 
          id: 1, 
          name: "item 1", 
          events:
          {
            click: this.handleClick,
            mouseenter: this.handleMouseEnter,
            mousemove: this.handleMouseMove,
          }
        },
        { 
          id: 2, 
          name: "item 2", 
          events:
          {
            click: this.handleClick,
          }
        },
        { 
          id: 3, 
          name: "item 3", 
          events:
          {
            mousemove: this.handleMouseMove,
          }
        },
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: 
  {
    handleClick(event) 
    {
      console.log("CLICK", event.target.dataset.id);
    },
    handleMouseEnter(event) 
    {
      console.log("MOUSE ENTER", event.target.dataset.id);
    },
    handleMouseMove(event) 
    {
      console.log("MOUSE MOVE", event.target.dataset.id);
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

You should make sure that your `item-component` is emitting the events that you're listening for.